# Elixir Mongodb driver: how do I orderby descending?

Tags: mongodb, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using the [currently most active mongodb driver](https://github.com/ankhers/mongodb) for Elixir (not using Ecto). I'd like to query with a limit but before that I need to order by descending. I have no idea how I would do this. The docs mention limit but not orderby:

```
Mongo.find(:mongo, "collection", %{"field" = "somefieldvalue"}, limit: 10)
```

Anybody know how to input the orderby a field if for example the field name was "time" and I wanted results ordered by time, descending?

If I type h Mongo.find in IEX I get an :order_by atom but not sure how I would use it if I want to specify a descending order.

Comment: Try `sort: %{time: -1}`: `Mongo.find(:mongo, "collection", %{"field" = "somefieldvalue"}, limit: 10, sort: %{time: -1})`

Comment: @Dogbert: bingo that works. Might want to turn it into an answer so that I can give it an accept.

Comment: @ThomasBrowne This was a bug in the documentation. This has been fixed a number of months ago and is already in the most recent version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a `sort` option to `Mongo.find/4`. The value of that key is passed as is to MongoDB. In MongoDB, you sort descending by a key by passing a map with the value of that key set to `-1` as documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/). The following should sort descending by the `time` key:

```
Mongo.find(:mongo, "collection", %{"field" = "somefieldvalue"}, limit: 10, sort: %{time: -1})
```